# OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"mysql\":

Tags: docker-compose

I'm getting:

> "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"mysql\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown" while passing below command
>   docker exec -i postgres postgres-u root -pmypassword mysql < db/cicd/build-artifacts/testreport/database.sql

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   postgres:
     image: mysql:5.7.10
     container_name: postgres
     ports:
       - 3306
     healthcheck:
       test: postgres --user=root --password=mypassword -e 'select version()'
       timeout: 1s
       retries: 5
     environment:
       postgres_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
       postgres_USER: root
       postgres_DATABASE: Dev
     volumes:
       - ./build-artifacts:/scripts       
     command: --postgres_mode=""

   dbfit:
      container_name: dbfit
      image: mattthinkwhere/dbfit
      ports:
        - 8085:8085
      volumes:
        - ./build-artifacts/dbfit_tests:/dbfit/FitNesseRoot/TestSuite
        - ./build-artifacts:/scripts      
      links:
        - postgres 
      depends_on:
       - postgres
```

Comment: Why are you using a MySQL image if you seem to be wanting to run Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

I think you used the wrong container ID. The message says he doesn't know the command "mysql" inside the container.